# statsmodels OLS fit computation time

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am using statsmodels.api for some simple OLS regression... And somehow every time I ran my script it got stuck at `model.fit` and I couldn't figure out why.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
```

`merged` is a pandas data frame as regressors and memoscore is a pandas data frame of one variable as my dependent variable. The following worked smoothly and instantly:

```
model = sm.OLS(np.array(memoscore), np.array(sm.add_constant(merged)))
results = model.fit()
```

Then I took the log of `memoscore`, the following still worked instantly:

```
memoscore_ln = np.log(memoscore)
model = sm.OLS(np.array(memoscore_ln), np.array(sm.add_constant(merged))
```

But it got stuck here forever:

```
results = model.fit()
```

Could anyone kindly suggest reason why and/or how to get around that? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: check for nan and infs in your data. Depending on the underlying linear algebra library, this could hang. OLS itself just does a bit of data preparation but essentially no computation.

Comment: @user333700, thanks so much for your comment. I've checked my observations, none of them are nan or infs... all of them looking good... I figure there is indeed a matrix to invert when implementing OLS, is it not?

Comment: Did you check the logged series memoscore_ln?  statsmodels.OLS uses a SVD by default to solve the linear least squares problem. MKL raises an error if invalid values are found, but some older LAPACK libraries never came back, or even segfaulted in some of the linalg operations with nans or infs.

Comment: @user333700, thanks again for your prompt reply!! Yes I did, I specifically checked if all memoscore_ln instances are numeric... They indeed are... so do all other variables included in `merged`... One thing occurred to me is that it could be some variables in `merged` is highly correlated... Could it be the cause of the problem here? If so, how come it went smoothly when `memscore` is not logged? Thanks so much.

Comment: Given that your linear model fitted fast, there cannot be a problem in the svd and the design matrix. (SVD is the best algorithm for near collinearity and regularizes if perfectly colinear within a threshold.) The source of the problem has to come from taking the log. Check if the values of memoscore_ln are within a reasonable range (e.g. np.min, np.max) and try clipping values to see if that helps. (clipping for debugging not for the final estimation.) Essentially, I don't have any suspects beside -inf in the array. Can you make the data available if this doesn't help?

Comment: Another option: try Poisson or GLM with a log-link with the (not logged) original data. This would have the same mean function for y, but use a variance that is a function of the (conditional) mean.

Answer (score 0):

I exported my data to R and ran the same OLS using `memoscore` and logged `memoscore` as the dependent variable, it worked like a charm. Still don't know what's wrong with `statsmodels`, but at least I learnt R is the go-to software for such easy regression tasks.

Comment: Did you check if R dropped observations?

Comment: @user333700, thanks for your suggestions! I checked and all the observations are kept...