# How do you get the adjusted R-squared for the test data in statsModels?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have a dataset like

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,3,4,6,6,3,2], 'b':[12,14,11,15,14,15,10]}
test = data.iloc[:4]
train = data.iloc[4:]
```

and I built the linear model for the train data

```
model = smf.ols("a ~ b", data = data)
print(model.fit().summary())
```

Now what I want to do is get the adjusted R^2 value based on the test data.  Is there a simple command for this?  I've been trying to build it from scratch and keep getting an error.

What I've been trying:

```
model.predict(test.b)
```

but it complains about the shape.  Based on this: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html

I tried the following

```
X = sm.add_constant(test.b)
model.predict(X)
```

Now the error is

```
ValueError: shapes (200,2) and (200,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 200 (dim 0)
```

The shape matches but then there's this thing I don't understand about the "dim".  But I thought I matched as well as I could the example in the link so I'm just not sure what's up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should first run the `.fit()` method and save the returned object and then run the `.predict()` method on that object.

```
results = model.fit()
```

Running `results.params` will produce this pandas Series:

```
Intercept   -0.875
b            0.375
dtype: float64
```

Then, running `results.predict(test.b)` will produce this Series:

```
0    3.625
1    4.375
2    3.250
3    4.750
dtype: float64
```

You can also retrieve model fit summary values by calling individual attributes of the results class (https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.html):

```
>>> results.rsquared_adj
0.08928571428571419
```

But those will be for the full/train model, so yes, you will probably need to manually compute SSR/SST/SSE values from your test predictions and true values, and get the adjusted R-squared from that.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, it no longer gives the error.  However, it now hangs in the computation without terminating.  The actual dataset that I have only has 400 entries. I'm still only making a linear model with one predictor.  So I don't think this should take more than a few seconds.  But if I let it go for a minute it still doesn't terminate.  Any thoughts about what might be causing this?

Comment: @Addem, you mean it hangs during execution of `fit()`?  I personally don't know the reason in your case, could be something in your data.  There is at least one post for a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860109/). The `fit()` method also has a [method](https://statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit.html) parameter that you could change.  If that does not help, maybe post a separate question.